# empty arrays in cython: segfault when calling PyArray_EMPTY

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

When I try to run the cython code below to generate an empty array, it segfaults.

**Is there any way of generating empty numpy arrays in python without calling `np.empty()`?**

```
cdef np.npy_intp *dims = [3]
cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] result = np.PyArray_EMPTY(1, dims, 
                                                            np.NPY_INTP, 0)
```

Comment: What is wrong about np.empty() ? If you're doing it only once at the initialization stage, you don't care if it's marginally slower than using C functions directly.

Comment: If you are performing operations on arrays of size <1000, the cost of np.empty() alone is greater than the entire loop. see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410342/creating-small-arrays-in-cython-takes-a-humongous-amount-of-time) where I described the problem. I'm trying to solve it, but now found a new problem: namely the use of the np.PyArray_EMPTY() function

Comment: Are `np.NPY_INTP` and `np.int_t` the same type in your system?

Comment: Is the first line really correct cython? It seems dubious to me.

Answer (score 3):

You might have solved this a long time ago, but for the benefit of anyone who stumbles across this question while trying to figure out why their cython code segfaults, here's a possible answer.

When you get a segfault when using the numpy C API, the first thing to check is that you have called the function `import_array()`.  That might be the problem here.

For example, here's `foo.pyx`:

```
cimport numpy as cnp


cnp.import_array()  # This must be called before using the numpy C API.

def bar():
    cdef cnp.npy_intp *dims = [3]
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=1] result = \
        cnp.PyArray_EMPTY(1, dims, cnp.NPY_INTP, 0)
    return result
```

Here's a simple `setup.py` for building the extension module:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np


setup(cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['foo.pyx'])],
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
```

Here's the module in action:

```
In [1]: import foo

In [2]: foo.bar()
Out[2]: array([4314271744, 4314271744, 4353385752])

In [3]: foo.bar()
Out[3]: array([0, 0, 0])
```