# Correct way to return numpy friendly arrays using typed memoryviews in Cython?

Tags: c, arrays, numpy, cython

I am trying to use Cython memoryviews *without* creating or taking numpy arrays, so that I never have to compile with numpy, but I'd like to return things that on the Python side can be 'cast' into numpy arrays. For example I have this function which takes a 2D array and returns a new 1d array:

```
cimport cython
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cpdef int[:] myfunc(int[:,:] input_arr, int arr_len):
   cdef int i
   # allocate new int array
   cdef int[:] new_arr = cvarray(shape=(arr_len,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i") 
   for i in xrange(arr_len):
      if input_arr[i, 0] == 1:
         new_arr[i] = 0
      else:
         new_arr[i] = 1
   return new_arr
```

and now from Python I actually want to pass a numpy array to the function and view the result as a numpy array:

```
# From Python
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,0,1]], dtype=np.dtype("i"))
result = myfunc(data, data.shape[0])
# How do I make 'result' accessible as numpy array here??
# ...
result = np.array(result)  # one possibility
```

How can that be done? Is the way I have it correct? More specific questions:

1. Does referencing `new_arr[x]` go back to Python? I'd like it to be pure C indexing of array
2. Is there a difference between `cdef int[:] new_arr = ...` and `cdef int[::1] new_arr = ...`? I don't understand the latter
3. Is `cvarray` the best way to allocate memory here, or `clone`? With numpy arrays I'd use `np.empty` and I am trying to get something as efficient here.  Also, why is `format="i"` needed in `cvarray` call.
4. **Finally**, if `clone` is right syntax, how can it be used for 2d arrays? It's unclear from https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/f94ad59754a0f0b1cef4a334b988a21392a738c0/Cython/Includes/cpython/array.pxd

This is related to this post ([What is the recommended way of allocating memory for a typed memory view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view)), which I did not fully understand.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are avoiding doing cimport numpy?  Doing np.array at the bottom there will make a copy if you don't specify both the dtype=np.int and copy=False.  Be careful about using the platform native int also, there are annoying problems that float around there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: @meawoppl: I don't want to require the numpy headers etc. I want simple Cython arrays and do not want to compile numpy headers with Cython. I don't mind making a copy on Python end.

Comment: I see, as aside then I would note that the headers ship with numpy and all the same calls to the same libraries will be made.  Numpy arrays are simply views downward on memory blocks.  If you specify the shape in the array creation step, or run reshape() its just returning a view where the strides attribute is different, so access in different dimensions can be read.  One option is doing all the accounting on this array about size/shape.  Another option is to pass in a numpy array and mutate it within your function.  This might be the easiest as it avoids the annoying refcounting semantics too

Comment: @meawoppl: an example of the reshape scheme you mention would help since I am not sure I follow. If I use cython arrays, won't that eliminate all the compiler warnings and other issues (like deprecated numpy apis)? I thought that if I don't use `np` anywhere and don't use `np.include_header()` in setup.py that I will be numpy-free, which is my goal. I don't want to depend on numpy C API at all when compiling the *.c files produced by Cython

Comment: You can use either `numpy.array` or `numpy.asarray` to get a NumPy array from a Cython memory view. `np.asarray` is really just a thin wrapper around `numpy.array`. I'm not so sure how you'll want to allocate the new array though. The example given in that other answer doesn't seem to work if you are copying a memory view.

Comment: Your comment about "numpy free" is a bit confusing given the first step outside of the cython code is to put the result in a numpy array.  Cython creates c-code from Python, which calls pythonXX.lib which calls numpy.libs.  You are creating c-code which calls things in pythonXX.lib, then making python code make c-calls to things in numpy.libs If the concern is a compiler warning, you can suppress that fairly easily.  Are you trying to divorce yourself from a particular numpy version?

Comment: @meawoppl: yes, I am fine with using numpy in Python side, but I don't want to use it from Cython because I don't want to rely on Cythin generating code that calls the *C* Numpy libraries. This is because: (1) they never compile without warnings, (2) cython generates some code that might use deprecated versions of numpy, so cython generated code could break on future numpy releases. that's why I don't want the numpy C library dependency but don't mind using numpy from pure python.

Comment: @user248237dfsf did you try the approach below?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you need to use this function somewhere else in Cython, you should use `def` instead of `cpdef`. To return a `numpy` array you can use `np.asarray()`, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

def myfunc(int[:,:] input_arr, int arr_len):
   cdef int i
   # allocate new int array
   cdef int[:] new_arr = cvarray(shape=(arr_len,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i") 
   for i in xrange(arr_len):
      if input_arr[i, 0] == 1:
         new_arr[i] = 0
      else:
         new_arr[i] = 1
   return np.asarray(new_arr)
```