# Cython's `cdef` raises a NameError where a `def` works just fine

Tags: python, cython

Maybe I am understanding the `cdef` for function definition incorrectly. E.g., assume I want to write a function to convert a Python list to a C array:

```
%%cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
cdef int* list_to_array(a_list):
    """ Converts a Python list into a C array """
    cdef int *c_array
    cdef int count, n
    c_array = <int *>malloc(len(a_list)*cython.sizeof(int))
    count = len(a_list)
    for i in range(count):
        c_array[i] = a_list[i]
    return c_array
```

when I call the function now via

```
list_to_array([1,2,3])
```

I get a

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8f3f777d7883> in <module>()
----> 1 list_to_array([1,2,3])

NameError: name 'list_to_array' is not defined
```

However, when I just use the `def`, the function can be called (although it doesn't return what I want, it is just for illustrating my problem...)

```
%%cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
def list_to_array1(a_list):
    """ Converts a Python list into a C array """
    cdef int *c_array
    cdef int count, n
    c_array = <int *>malloc(len(a_list)*cython.sizeof(int))
    count = len(a_list)
    for i in range(count):
        c_array[i] = a_list[i]
    return 1


list_to_array1([1,2,3])

1
```

When I tried to use `cpdef` instead of `cdef`, I encounter a different issue:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
cpdef int* list_to_carray(a_list):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/sebastian/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_c979dc7a52cdfb492e901a4b337ed2d2.pyx:3:6: Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object
```

Answer (score 1):

Citing the [docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html), "The `cdef` statement is used to make C level declarations"

Then if you scroll a bit down [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#callable-from-c), you see that `cdef` functions can not be called from python, hence your NameError. Try using `cpdef`.

Note that if you plan to use that function in python code it will leak memory. You may also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620255/passing-input-output-to-from-functions-in-cython/23620595#23620595) answer on how/why you should return pass a list to/from cython (disclaimer: the answer is mine) to avoid the leakage.

EDIT, in reply to updated question:

The error once you introduce `cpdef` happens because a pointer cannot be converted to a python object in a trivial way. Cython does the hard work for you in the simplest cases, see [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#automatic-type-conversion). The question you should ask here is why you want to return a C pointer to the python environment, that does not provide pointers.

Comment: Thanks, I have a second function `array_to_pythonlist` that would take care of the memory leak via `libc.stdlib.free(c_array)` but I didn't mention it because it was not directly related to the issue of the question

Comment: Abput cpdef: I tried it before, and got a `Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object` , I will post the complete error in the question above. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Ok. you're however incurring in 2 copy overhead. If you pass in to cython a numpy array you don't have to copy to/from a c allocated block.

Comment: The point why I am doing this is to compare it to a numpy array approach (in terms of a benchmark). When I am using numpy arrays as input, I noticed that this approach is "slower" than using C arrays, I have the benchmark here if you are interested: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rasbt/One-Python-benchmark-per-day/blob/master/htmls/day4_python_cython_numba.html

Comment: I still don't see why you need to return a C pointer to python. Open a new question on the performance of the 2 approaches, the question is interesting IMHO. I would try using `xrange` instead of `range`, and would try using `cpdef` instead of `def` where you declare the 2 tests `cython_bubblesort_clist` and `cython_bubblesort_numpy`. I think you should also try [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html#efficient-indexing) for efficient indexing.

Comment: and disable bound checking, writing `@cython.boundscheck(False)` just before the definition of the 2 functions

Comment: about xrange: I am using Python 3.x - in Python 3.x range() has been implemented as xrange()

Comment: about why I want to return a c-pointer: I want to pass the c-array to the bubblesort cython implementation to benchmark it without doing the conversion from python list to c array internally in the function itself

Comment: @cython.boundscheck(False) didn't help, `cpdef` still doesn't work, and I also still get the NameError with `cdef` (but as you said `cdef` wouldn't work either way within Python)

Comment: in reply to your first comment of the 2. The cython implementation is not a python function, it should be declared with `cpdef` and can then accept a pointer. Your 2nd comment is inconclusive. You insisted not asking a new question about the performance of your benchmark, you have my -1.

Comment: sorry, I just posted the question about the benchmark here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661636/poorer-performance-of-cython-with-numpy-array-memoryview-compared-to-c-arrays

Comment: `cpdef` causes the code to not compile: `@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef int* list_to_carray(a_list):` with an error `Cannot convert 'int *' to Python object`

Comment: the cpdef should be used on the cython implementation of the sort, not on `list_to_carray`.