# Should list item type be defined in cython?

Tags: python, list, cython

If I send a python list to a cython function to iterate over, am I suppose to declare what type the list items are? Also what is the best way to loop over a list in cython? For example:

```
#Cython function, passed a list of float items
def cython_f(list example_list):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(example_list)):
        #Do stuff
        #but list item type not defined?
        pass

    #Alternative loop
    cdef j float #declaration of list item type
    for j in example_list:
        #Do stuff
        pass
```

Is any speed gained from trying to define list item type? Is it preferable to pass numpy arrays instead of python lists?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Cython you are not obliged to declare anything. Declaring types *usually* helps with performance. The *usually* is because if you declare types, but then don't use them, you may induce type checks and pack-unpack. The only way to be sure is to measure.

To declare the types of the list, just put at the beginning `cdef float value`, and in the loop `value = example_list[i]`.

Should you use list or numpy array? An array is an uniform data container. This means that you can declare it as being `float32_t`, and Cython will know how to work with that at C speed (accessing is faster, as it is guaranteed to be contiguous and strided in memory). On the other hand, if you are going to change the size, you are probably better using lists (or for very heavy use, perhaps `libcpp.vector`). So the answer is it depends on what you do, but in most cases, an array is better.

To be fair, you have to consider how is the data living. If you have everything in lists, your function with arrays may be faster, but `list -> array -> f_array -> array -> list` may be slower than `list -> f_list -> list`. If you don't care, as a rule of thumb, use arrays when the length will be constant and lists otherwise. Also note that numpy arrays are lighter on the memory for big amounts of data.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are several good, more integrated, alternatives to `libcpp.vector`, namely `cpython.array` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view). The best choice obviously depends on context.