# How to specify list and tuple type in cython

Tags: python, optimization, types, cython

I have a simple function which transforms a list of a bonds between nodes into a list of neighboring nodes. The input is "list of tuples of integers" and the output "list of lists of integers," e.g.

```
 input:  bonds     = [(1,2), (1,4)]
 output: neighbors = [[],[2,4],[1],[],[1]]
```

Is there anything I can do to specify these types more precisely so that Cython can optimize it better? The function looks like this:

```
def bonds2neighs( list bonds, int natom ):
    cdef:
        int  ii
        list neighbors = [ [] for ii in xrange(natom) ]
        int i,j
    for i,j in bonds: 
        neighbors[i].append(j)
        neighbors[j].append(i)
    return neighbors
```

Comment: While the question is stated clearly, re: coding style, maybe you want to use a different word than "neighs?" A neigh is the sound a horse makes, and it also sounds like "nay," a way to say no. Unfortunately, there's no good abbreviation I can think of for neighbors, but I think spelling "neighbors" out is okay.

Also, can we assume that all integers from 1 to n will be covered, with no gaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705255/should-list-item-type-be-defined-in-cython

Answer (score 2):

The builtin Python types `list`, `tuple`, `dict` and so on are not generic. They are containers of the basic `*PyObject`. You cannot specify a type such as `list[tuple[int, int]]` because there is no such thing.

Cython's only support for quasi-generics are [fused types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html). They are akin to a mixture of templating and unions, which allow to specify up-front a fixed set of possible types. However, they cannot be used with extension types and thus do not allow to create generic containers.

> Fused types are not currently supported as attributes of extension
>   types. Only variables and function/method arguments can be declared
>   with fused types.