# What is the best way of allocating array of bytes in Cython and passing it back to Python?

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I have a Cython function like `cdef generate_data(size)` where I'd like to:

- initialise an array of bytes of length `size`
- call external (`C`) function to populate the array using array ptr and size
- return the array as something understandable by Python (bytearray, bytes, your suggestions)

I have seen many approaches on the internet but I'm looking for the best/recommended way of doing this in my simple case. I want to:

- avoid memory reallocations
- avoid using numpy
- ideally use something that works in Python 3 and 2.7, although a 2.7 solution is good enough.

I'm using Cython 0.20.

Comment: I believe you have to be more specific in order to get good answers...

Comment: I wanted to be as generic as possible since I wanted to know the typical (canonical?) way of solving this class of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For allocating memory, [I have you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view).

After that, just take a pointer (possibly at the `data` attribute if you use `cpython.array.array` like I recommend) and pass that along. You can return the `cpython.array.array` type and it will become a Python array.