# Memoryview on c array in cython

Tags: python, c, cython, memoryview

Error initializing memoryview variable. This is my code:

```
cdef int *popref = <int*>malloc(popsize * sizeof(int))
cdef int [:] popref_mv = popref
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Error: cdef int [:] popref_mv = popref
         ^
   Expected an identifier or literal
```

Running Python 2.6.6, GCC 4.4.7, Cython 0.14.1 on Red Hat Linux.

Comment: Hmh, I don't think this will work without type casting: `cdef int [:] popref_mv = <int[:size]> popref`

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view) helps you `malloc` may circumvent for memoryview

Comment: Typecasting does not work....Tried it out already

Comment: Does it have to do something with the version of python I am using??