# cython - determining the number of items in pointer variable

Tags: pointers, cython

How would I determine the number of elements in a pointer variable in cython? I saw that in C one way seems to be `sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(int)`, if the pointer points to `int` variables. But that doesn't seem to work in cython. E.g. when I tried to join two memory views into a single pointer like so:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
cdef int * join(int[:] a, int[:] b):

    cdef:
        int n_a = a.shape[0]
        int n_b = b.shape[0]
        int new_size =  n_a + n_b
        int *joined = <int *> malloc(new_size*sizeof(int))
        int i
    try:
        for i in range(n_a):
            joined[i] = a[i]

        for i in range(n_b):
            joined[n_a+i] = b[i]

        return joined
    finally:
        free(joined)

@cython.cdivision(True)
def join_memviews(int[:] n, int[:] m):

    cdef int[:] arr_fst = n
    cdef int[:] arr_snd = m
    cdef int *arr_new
    cdef int new_size

    arr_new = join(arr_fst,arr_snd)    
    new_size = sizeof(arr_new)/sizeof(int)

    return [arr_new[i] for i in range(new_size)]
```

I do not get the desired result when calling `join_memviews` from a python script, e.g.:

```
# in python
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4])
a_b = join_memviews(a,b)
```

I also tried using the types

```
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
```

as the arguement inside `sizeof()`, but that didn't work either.

**Edit**: The handling of the pointer variable was apparently a bit careless of me. I hope the following is fine (even though it might not be a prudent approach):

```
cdef int * join(int[:] a, int[:] b, int new_size):

    cdef:
        int *joined = <int *> malloc(new_size*sizeof(int))
        int i

    for i in range(n_a):
        joined[i] = a[i]

    for i in range(n_b):
        joined[n_a+i] = b[i]

    return joined

def join_memviews(int[:] n, int[:] m):

    cdef int[:] arr_fst = n
    cdef int[:] arr_snd = m
    cdef int *arr_new
    cdef int new_size = n.shape[0] + m.shape[0]

    try: 
        arr_new = join(arr_fst,arr_snd, new_size)    

        return [arr_new[i] for i in range(new_size)]
    finally:
        free(arr_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It doesn't work in C either. `sizeof(ptr)` returns the amount of memory used to store the pointer (i.e. typically 4 or 8 depending on your system) rather than the length of the array. The lengths of your `malloc`ed arrays are something that you need to keep track of manually.

Additionally the following code is a recipe for disaster:

```
cdef int *joined = <int *> malloc(new_size*sizeof(int))
try:
   return joined
finally:
   free(joined)
```

The `free` happens immediately on function exit so that an invalid pointer is returned to the calling function.

---

You should be using properly managed Python arrays (either from numpy or the standard library `array` module) unless you absolutely can't avoid it.

Comment: thanks for these clarifications. Regarding the `try-finally` part, I thought that `joined` would be copied to the variable to which the function returns, before it is freed. But I haven't checked, so thanks for the warning. I edit the code that it should work properly, though it might not be a sensible approach.

Comment: Your edit looks like it should work. However, I'd be tempted to just use numpy to do the same task: `np.concatenate((a,b))`

Comment: of course, if I would just want to join two arrays, I would use numpy. but I have the need to join memory views within a larger task implemented in cython. Because that happens quite a lot and because I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view/21054369#21054369) that the malloc-approach offers fast initalization and access via iteration, I wanted to try it that way. Still, I should probably first try the save thing and than profile.