# Cython: how to get the 'actual Python type' (type code/dtype) from C-level type

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, cython

I'd like to allocate stack memory for a memoryview defined with a ctypedef, and return it as numpy ndarray. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view) discussed a few allocation methods, but the catch is I don't know how to programatically map my custom ctypedef to the corresponding numpy dtype or Python type code, which are needed for the allocation.

For example:

```
from cython cimport view
import numpy as np

ctypedef int value_type    # actual type subject to change

# np.empty requires me knowing that Cython int maps to np.int32
def test_return_np_array(size_t N):
    cdef value_type[:] b = np.empty(N, dtype=np.int32)
    b[0]=12                  # from ctypedef int ^
    return np.asarray(b)
# or, Cython memoryview requires the type code 'i'
def test_return_np_array(size_t N):
    cdef value_type[:] b = view.array(shape=(N,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i")
    b[0]=12                                                 # from ctypedef int ^
    return np.asarray(b)
```

I'm using the typedef so that I can flexibly change the actual data type (say from `int` to `long long`) without having to modify all the code.

In pure Python, type checking is easy:

```
value_type = int
print(value_type is int)    # True
print(value_type is float)  # False
```

In numpy this can also be easily achieved by parameterizing the dtype as a string, like `value_type="int32"` then calling `np.empty(N, dtype=value_type)`. With my ctypedef, Cython won't compile `np.empty(N, dtype=value_type)`, and complains "'value_type' is not a constant, variable or function identifier". Is it possible to achieve something like this at compile time?

The user shouldn't have to manage the returned memory, so `malloc` won't be an option.

I came up with a hack using C++ vector: `<value_type[:N]>vector[value_type](N).data()`, but this seems to cause memory errors.

Comment: My workaround is to manually define both a runtime type and corresponding compile-time type, like `value_type = np.int32` and `ctypedef np.int32_t value_type_t` (which can be easily changed to `value_type = np.int64` and `ctypedef np.int64_t value_type_t`), based on the mapping in `/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd`. It's also mentioned [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html#adding-types).

Comment: You are right this is the simplest solution to start with. I've updated my answer with some considerations, which explains why a more robust approach might be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

From C's point of view `np.int32` is not a type but a Python-object, which must be created at run time and cannot  be created at compile time.

Probably the most robust way is this trick (for an explanation of details see this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62448946/5769463)):

```
%%cython -a 

import numpy as np

def GET_SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE():
    cdef int tmp
    return np.asarray(<int[:1]>(&tmp)).dtype
```

and now

```
>>> print(GET_SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE())
int32
```

The advantage is, that Cython-infrastructure is used for the mapping and no manual error-prone work is needed.

---

A less enigmatic but also more error-prone approach: you could pick the right type through a function which is called at run time, when the module is loaded:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np

ctypedef int value_type 

SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE_MAP = {2 : np.int16, 4 : np.int32, 8 : np.int64}
SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE = SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE_MAP[sizeof(value_type)]

def zeros(N):
    return np.zeros(N, dtype=SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE)
```

and now:

```
>>> print(zeros(1).dtype)
int32
```

Changing `int` to `long long` would lead to `np.int64` being picked.

A similar approach could also be used for memory-views.

---

As you have pointed out, the Cython tutorial recommends to map the types manually, e.g.:

```
ctypedef np.int32_t value_type
SIGNED_NUMPY_TYPE = np.int32
```

and then change both manually, if needed. This simple solution is probably the best for smaller programs and prototypes. However, there are some consideration which could call for a more robust approach:

- When both defines are placed next to each other, it is easy to see that they have to be changed together. For more complex program the two definitions can  placed in different pxd or pyx files, and then it is only a question of time until this breaks.
- As long as fixed size types (`int32`, `int64`) are used, the corresponding numpy type is obvious. However for types like `int` and `long` it is not easy to tell:

  - `int` is only guaranteed to have at least 2 and not more bytes than `long`. The compiler can decide which size is picked, It might be slightly worrying that there are no guarantee, however the usual suspects (gcc, cland, icc and msvc) choose 4 bytes for the usual architectures.
  - `long` is already a pitfall: gcc choose it to be 8 bytes for Linux64, but in msvc `long` is only 4 bytes long so without knowing which compiler will be used, one cannot choose between `np.int32` and `np.int64` in advance.
  - For the case of `long` there is `np.int` which is quite confusing, because one would expect `np.int` to map to `int` and not `long`! However on Linux64/gcc `np.int.itemsize` is 8 bytes, but `int` is only 4 bytes long. On the other hand on Windows64/msvc both `np.int` and `int` are 4 bytes.