# Creating a numpy datatype from Cython struct

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Following is a Cython code snippet currently used in scikit-learn binary trees,

```
  # Some compound datatypes used below:
  cdef struct NodeHeapData_t:
      DTYPE_t val
      ITYPE_t i1
      ITYPE_t i2

  # build the corresponding numpy dtype for NodeHeapData
  cdef NodeHeapData_t nhd_tmp
  NodeHeapData = np.asarray(<NodeHeapData_t[:1]>(&nhd_tmp)).dtype
```

(full source [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/89b80a6c67add0e199f2c5c8ff61cf2e667f3dbc/sklearn/neighbors/_binary_tree.pxi#L177-L184))

The last line creates a numpy dtype from this Cython struct. I haven't been able to find much documentation about it, and in particular I don't understand why the slicing `[:1]` is needed or what it does.  More discussion can be found in [scikit-learn#17228](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/17228#issuecomment-642289818). Would anyone have ideas about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a clever but confusing trick!

The following code creates a [cython-array](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays)  of length 1, because the memory it uses (but not owns!) has exact one element.

```
cdef NodeHeapData_t nhd_tmp
<NodeHeapData_t[:1]>(&nhd_tmp)
```

Now, cython-array implements buffer-protocol and thus Cython has the machinery to create a [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.Py_buffer.format)-string which describes the type of the element it holds.

`np.asarray` uses also the buffer-protocol and is able to construct a `dtype`-object from the `format`-string, which is provided by cython's array.

You can see the format-string via:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np

# Some compound datatypes used below:
cdef struct NodeHeapData_t:
  double val
  int i1
  int i2

# build the corresponding numpy dtype for NodeHeapData
cdef NodeHeapData_t nhd_tmp
NodeHeapData = np.asarray(<NodeHeapData_t[:1]>(&nhd_tmp)).dtype

print("format string:",memoryview(<NodeHeapData_t[:1]>(&nhd_tmp)).format)
print(NodeHeapData )
```

which leads to

```
format string: T{d:val:i:i1:i:i2:}
[('val', '<f8'), ('i1', '<i4'), ('i2', '<i4')]
```

Off the top of my head, I cannot come up with a less confusing solution, other than creating `dtype`-object by hand - which might get ugly for some data types on different platforms*, but should be straight forward for most cases.

---

*) `np.int` is such a problematic case. It is easy to overlook that `np.int` maps onto `long` and not  `int` (confusing, isn't?).

For example

```
memoryview(np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int)).itemsize
```

evaluates to

- On Windows: 4 (size of `long` in bytes on Windows).
- On Linux: 8 (size of `long` in bytes on Linux).

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed explanation! I would have never found this by myself :)

Comment: As mentionned by @jeremiedbb this is also briefly documented in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy

Comment: @ead is this possible when you also have arrays within the struct? E.g. `vector[int] weights`?

Comment: @ajl123 No, vector is a C++ construct - there is no format string for it. Also IIRC memory layout of a std::vector is implementation dependent.

Comment: I noticed that if you try this trick with a struct only consisting of two `float` values, the dtype is incorrectly returned as `dtype('complex64')`.