# Best way to allocate a cython memoryview of uint32_t

Tags: python, cython

I'd like to allocate, zero-initialize and return a cython memoryview of an aribitrary number of elements. Element type should be uint32_t (and in some cases uint16_t).

A problem seems to be to find the right format code for the fixed size integer type, is there a good way to do this, or does it come down to testing each of the alternatives (for example using struct.calcsize)?

(Without using numpy.)

Comment: I tend to just let NumPy create the contiguous arrays. Then you can pass them through to C functions in Cython just by using &arrayname[0], and you get the memory management for free because it's a Python object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler supports `stdint.h`, `int32_t` (and similar) could be cimported from `libc.stdint`:

```
%%cython

from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

def create(len):
    cdef uint32_t[:] memview = cvarray(shape=(len,), itemsize=sizeof(uint32_t), format=b"=I")
    return memview
```

Memory view needs to be backed by something, that owns the memory - I have chosen cython's array.

Also `format=b"=I"` is used. Important here is the character `=` which [guarantees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) the ["standard"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) `itemsize` of 4bytes (which `b"I"` does not by the way). An alternative would be [to create the format string at the run time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62448946/5769463) as, e.g.

```
%%cython

...
cdef uint32_t tmp = 1
fuint32_t = (<uint32_t[:1]>(&tmp)).format  # use this to create carray
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation that supports that `=I` is a supported format string? It seems underdocumented.

Comment: @creanion I've added links to documenation

Comment: I think it's the cython array that is lacking documentation and doesn't document this