# How to dynamically allocate memory for multidimension memoryview inside a cdef function using CPython array

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I am trying to use cython to work on and output (numpy) array. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462785/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-allocating-memory-for-a-typed-memory-view/21054369#21054369) which explains how to do it using cpython array. For example:

```
from cpython.array import array, clone
def int[:] foo1d(int m):
    cdef int[:] mv;
    cdef array template = array('i', [])
    mv = clone(template, m, True)
    return mv
```

However I am wondering how to do this for multidimensional typed memoryview. For example, I can do this with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef int[:,:] foo2d(int m, int n):
    cdef int[:,:] mv;
    mv = np.zeros((m, n), dtype=int)
    return mv
```

But I couldn't find how to do this with cpython.array. I appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: Python's array.arrays are one-dimensional (numpy's array are ndarrays, i.e. multidimensional) and thus not support more than one dimension. You could however use Cython's arrays: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays

Comment: Got it. Thanks @ead !